# Populate List of entity class objects from sql ResultSet

Tags: java, sql

So I have this sql query:

```
    "select company, surveys.surveyID, questionID, question, questionScore FROM surveys INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM companies INNER JOIN "
            + "(SELECT * FROM questions INNER JOIN categories "
            + "ON questions.catID = categories.catID) AS cats "
            + "ON companies.questionID = cats.questionID) AS yes "
            + "ON yes.surveyID = surveys.surveyID WHERE company=?"
```

'cats' and 'yes' have no meaning and are just victums of my extremely verbose naming scheme.

company is just a string.

The table it returns would look like this:

```
 ---------------------------------------------
|companyName|surveyID|questionID|questionScore|
 ---------------------------------------------
```

The primary key for this table is (companyName, surveyID AND QuestionID) because each company can have multiple surveys, each survey has a number of questions.

Then I have this class:

```
public class Company
{
private String companyName;
private String surveyorName;
private String surveyorTitle;
private int surveyID;
private Map<Integer,Integer> questions;

public Company(String name, String surveyor, String surveyerTitle,
    int surveyID, Map<Integer, Integer> questions)
{
this.companyName = name;
this.surveyorName = surveyor;
this.surveyorTitle = surveyerTitle;
this.surveyID = surveyID;
this.questions = questions;
}
```

With a all the getters and setters

For example, say there is a company Mens Insamen. SurveyID is 1.
So

```
Mens Insamen    1       q1     3
Mens Insamen    1       q2     1
```

etc...

Now I need to populate a List of Company objects with the data from the sql query. I have tried for a while but couldn't really come up with anything.

If it is (unsurprisingly) unclear (fokol (no) coffee) I can improve it at some point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should really have shown the code that represents your attempt towards doing this. It's just a bunch of boilerplate code, anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? Are you able to do sql-queries in java? You already have a query, what the result is, and an object. You can do the query, and for each result make an object, populate it, and put it in your list. Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this simply using arraylist and your while loop
Create your arraylist for compines just outside the loop and 
 add each Company object to this array list using the loop

```
ArrayList<Company> compList = new ArrayList<Company>();

while{

/*read  values to variables and create an object of Company 
  then add to arraylist as follows **/

Company comp = new Company (name, surveyor, surveyerTitle,surveyID,questions);    
compList.add(comp);
}
```

Comment: I think you are able to produce the result of query using while loop then what you have to do is as in my answer just create a new object for each row from the query and add it to an arraylist that was declared out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

create class CompanyMapper have a method inside it, pass that method the SQL ResultSet as input, loop thru it and create a list of Company and return it.

```
class CompanyMapper{

public List<Company> getCompanies(ResultSet rs){

    ArrayList<Company> compList = new ArrayList<Company>();
    while(...rs has entry...){
        //Add new Company to the list
    }
return compList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to tell, what you have so far from the question, but if you want to populate a list of your custom objects, then you need to do something like this:

```
public List<Company> getCompanies() throws SQLException
{
    List<Company> result = new ArrayList<Company>();

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery("your query here");

    set.beforeFirst();
    while(set.next())
    {
        String textData = set.getString("columnname");
        int integerData = set.getInt("columnname");

        // you can also use set.getString(columnindex);

        Company company = new Company();
        company.set(...);

        result.add(company);
    }
    connection.close();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You should create a connection to the database using,

```
Class.forName(DB_LIBRARY);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_PARAMETRS);
```

Note that you need to replace DB_LIBRARY with the valid driver's library, and CONNECTION_PARAMETERS with your database connection setting (eg. host name, user name, password, ..etc).

2- create a statement, and return a result set

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(your_select_query);
```

3- loop through the result set and fetch data

```
Company company;
while(rs.next()){
         company = new Company(rs.getString(1), 
         rs.getString(2), 
         rs.getString(3), 
         rs.getInt(4),
         new HashMap<Integer, Integer>().put(rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6)
}
```

Note that you can use columns name or their number, also you may use an ArrayList if you want to fetch more than one record, as following

```
ArrayList<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();
while(rs.next()){
         companies.add(new Company(rs.getString(1), 
         rs.getString(2), 
         rs.getString(3), 
         rs.getInt(4),
         new HashMap<Integer, Integer>().put(rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6));
}
```